# WooCommerce - Getting completed status orders by user in a period of time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I need to get a user's done purchases in the last month by USER ID in Woocommerce.

Users have levels (Gold, Silver):

- Gold members can purchase 4 items each month;
- Silver members can buy 1 item per month.

I need to check this before adding an item to the cart. I don't want to use a plugin for just this feature (which could not found, BTW).

Is that possible? 
How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: "I don't want to use a plugin for just this feature" you're going to have to write one. You should start with [this tutorial](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-all-woocommerce-orders-for-a-customer/). Orders are a simple `WP_Query` and you can use date parameters to refine further. Though Orders are different from Order Items, so I'm not sure which you need. Post your code so we can guide you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to get the **total items count bought** by the **current customer in the past 30 days**.

Here is the code of this function [**based on this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/38875458#38875458):

```
function current_customer_month_count( $user_id=null ) {
    if ( empty($user_id) ){
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    }
    // Date calculations to limit the query
    $today_year = date( 'Y' );
    $today_month = date( 'm' );
    $day = date( 'd' );
    if ($today_month == '01') {
        $month = '12';
        $year = $today_year - 1;
    } else{
        $month = $today_month - 1;
        $month = sprintf("%02d", $month);
        $year = $today_year - 1;
    }

    // ORDERS FOR LAST 30 DAYS (Time calculations)
    $now = strtotime('now');
    // Set the gap time (here 30 days)
    $gap_days = 30;
    $gap_days_in_seconds = 60*60*24*$gap_days;
    $gap_time = $now - $gap_days_in_seconds;

    // The query arguments
    $args = array(
        // WC orders post type
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        // Only orders with status "completed" (others common status: 'wc-on-hold' or 'wc-processing')
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', 
        // all posts
        'numberposts' => -1,
        // for current user id
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'date_query' => array(
            //orders published on last 30 days
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'year' => $today_year,
                'month' => $today_month,
            ),
            array(
                'year' => $year,
                'month' => $month,
            ),
        ),
    );

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( $args );
    $count = 0;
    if (!empty($customer_orders)) {
        $customer_orders_date = array();
        // Going through each current customer orders
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ){
            // Conveting order dates in seconds
            $customer_order_date = strtotime($customer_order->post_date);
            // Only past 30 days orders
            if ( $customer_order_date > $gap_time ) {
                $customer_order_date;
                $order = new WC_Order( $customer_order->ID );
                $order_items = $order->get_items();
                // Going through each current customer items in the order
                foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ){
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The function accept an optional **`user_id`** argument (if needed). For example for a **`user_id`** with **`56`** value, you will use the function, this way:

```
// For user ID: "56".
$number_of_items_in_last_month = current_customer_month_count('56');
```

The function will get **the current user ID** in **`$user_id = get_current_user_id();`**, if you dont set an argument **`user_id`** value, this way:

```
// For current logged user.
$number_of_items_in_last_month = current_customer_month_count();
```

> You can use this function in a conditional if statement to hide or replace the add-to-cart button through somme WooCommerce [**hooks**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) or [**related templates**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). 
>   *You could get helped in that task, asking a new question including this code, and providing more details about how you want to do it.*

**This code is tested and works.**

---

References: [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/38875458#38875458)