# Showing a product to registered users that haven't purchase it yet in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, product

I wanted to show a product only when the user has registered and has not bought this product (new user product).

After they buy this product once, it is no longer available to that user to purchase (because it's a 1-shot deal).

So this means after I bought it, and do things like try to navigate directly to that product's URL, or do a search for all products, etc, this item would not show up.

If I was a new user and didn't buy it, of course, it should show up everywhere.

I have a custom property (metadata) on a user that indicates whether they buy it or not. After they purchase it, I will set this user flag to true indicating it can no longer show.

I had two questions:

1. Is there a way to hook into the actual successful purchasing of an item, and set this user flag to be true?
2. How can I instruct Woo to not show this product for a certain user when their flag is true?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible trough 3 functions:

**1) A conditional function** that will check that customer has bought your specific product:

```
function has_bought_items( $user_id = 0, $product_id = 0 ) {
    // The customer ID
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 || $user_id == '' ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;

    // Retrieve your customer flag '_has_bought_flag' (or replace it by your slug)
    if ( get_user_meta( $customer_id, '_has_bought_flag', true ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**2) A custom function** hooked in **`pre_get_posts`** that will change the WP_Query on shop and archives pages, checking if user is logged in and if he has already bought this specific product:

```
// Changing the WP_Query loop conditionally
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'conditional_product_query', 10, 1 );
function conditional_product_query( $q ) {

    // HERE set your product ID
    $product_id = 37;

    if( ! is_user_logged_in() || has_bought_items( '', $product_id ) )
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', array($product_id) );
}
```

> **It will remove completely this product everywhere, when the condition match**.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**3) A custom function** hooked in **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** that will set the customer flag when order status get "completed" when the product is in that order and when the customer flag doesn't exist yet:

```
// When Order get the "completed" status (paid) we check and we set the user flag (if necessary)
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'set_customer_specific_product_flag', 10, 2 );
function set_customer_specific_product_flag( $order_id, $order ) {

    // HERE set your product ID
    $product_id = 37;

    // If customer has already bought the product we exit
    if( has_bought_items( $order->get_user_id(), $product_id ) ) return;

    // Checking order items (if it match we update user meta data
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $product_item ){
        if ( $product_item->get_product_id() == $product_id ){
            update_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), '_has_bought_flag', '1' );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works (It should work on previous versions too).

---

Related answer: [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/46216073#46216073)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking the time out to write this for me. Merci!

Comment: Hey @loictheaztec while this hides almost everywhere, if I go to the /shop URL (which can be accessed either directly, or if my cart session expires and it asks me to add new products again) then it shows me 2 rows. The first row contains all my products, the second row contains all my products except the one I want to hide. So not sure why the first row shows buts second hides - is there another loop or hook I need to hook into to hide it here? that /shop endpoint seems to be pulling in the product still