# Check for new customers in WooCommerce Order received (Thankyou) page

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am trying to show a custom message to new all customer (not returning customer) in Thankyou page and  I am using *"[Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/46216073#46216073)"* answer code.

The issue is that can't detect if a customer has bought before. For example if I use the current code in thank You page the new customer become older customer.

SO my question is: How can I check if a customer bought earlier any product not in the current order?

Here is my code attempt, that doesn't work as it should:

```
function has_bought_before( $user_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $paid_order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
    " );

    // Count number of orders and return a boolean value depending if higher than 0
    return count( $results ) > 0 ? true : false;
}



add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'woo_change_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
function woo_change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
    if( has_bought_before() ){
        $new_str = $str . ' Welcome Back Again.';
    }else{
        $new_str = $str . ' Welcome To our site You will get 10% discount on your next order.';
    }
    return $new_str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **thankyou** page you are targeting the next paid order, so you need to make a little change in the conditional function `has_bought_before()`, at the end, replacing the line:

```
return count( $results ) > 0 ? true : false;
```

by:

```
return count( $results ) > 1 ? true : false;
```

It should be working as you expect now.

May be rename this conditional function `thankyou_has_bought_before()`.

Comment: Thanks it works :) I think woocommerce is Like ABC for you.