# Get WooCommerce product purchase date from a product Id for a user Id

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, date, woocommerce

I have faced a problem. I need to get a specific product purchase date using the user id and product id. Using *"[Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/38875458#38875458)"* answer code, it checks all product in the following:

```
function has_bought() {
    $customer_orders = get_posts( 
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
        ) 
    );
   return count($customer_orders) > 0 ? true : false; 
}
if( has_bought() )
    echo '<p>You have already maid a purchase</p>';
else
    echo '<p>Welcome, for your first purchase you will get a discount of 10%</p>';
```

What I need is to check specific product purchase data using the user id and product id.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I want to understand better what is your target. From the code I understand you wish to give a first time purchase of 10%, if the user hasn't purchased this product before? if yes, why do you need the date of the purchase?

Another question, if the user has purchased this product before several times, which date will you need?

Comment: I need just a specific product purchase date by `user id` and `product id`. If he bought the same product again then need last purchase date of product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **direct** custom SQL Query, avoiding looping through order items to find out the targeted product, will make the database query and the php process much more lighter and effective.

The query checks all product types, **including variable products** and **product variations** too.

Now for the date here we use the order **post date**.

So here is the custom query embedded in a function (returns a date or an empty value):

```
function get_product_purchased_last_date( $product_id, $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT p.post_date FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items oi ON oi.order_id = p.ID
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND p.post_status = 'wc-completed'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND pm.meta_value = '%d'
        AND oim.meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id') AND oim.meta_value = '%d'
        ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIT 1
    ", $user_id, $product_id ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE example** *(on current product page, for the current user Id)*:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if( $date = get_product_purchased_last_date( get_the_id(), get_current_user_id() ) ) {
        $text = sprintf( __("You have already purchased this product the %s"), date( "jS \of F Y", strtotime($date) ) );
    } else {
        $text =  __("Welcome, for your first purchase you will get a discount of 10%");
    }
    // Display
    echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to you comments, you will need to loop through orders and check if the product ID exists. if yes, it will return the date, otherwise it will return false.

```
function check_date_purchased($user_id, $product_id){ 
    $args = array(
        "posts_per_page" => -1,
        "customer_id" => $user_id,
        "orderby" => 'date',
        "order" => 'DESC',
        "status" => "completed", // maybe limit this to completed and processing,
    );
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    foreach( $orders as $order_id ) {
       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
       $items = $order->get_items();
       foreach ($items as $order_item){
          if ($product_id == $order_item->get_product_id()) return $order->order_date;
       }
    }
   return false;
}
```

**(Did not tested)**