# How to add a first order column to the admin order list for customers and guests

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I would like to add a column in the "admin order list" page of WooCommerce, which informs me if the user is the first time that he buys.

I think this "[Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce)" can be used for my case.

But I don't know how to add it in a column on the "orders" page of WooCommerce

Comment: this is certainly possible, but it is the intention to show what you have tried so far to achieve this result. not that someone else is going to do this for you

Comment: Ok thanks, actually I haven't tried anything yet. however I found a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce).
i think the function can be used for my case. but I don't know how to add it in a column on the "orders" page of woocommerce

Answer (score 1):

> With `manage_edit-shop_order_columns` & `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column`
> you can add a new column.
>
> With [`wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id )`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_customer_order_count/) you get the total orders by a customer.

---

> **Note 1:** Because guests don't have a `$user_id`, we use the [`$billing_email`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#607) to determine the current and previous orders.

> **Note 2:** I partly used the following [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216073/11987538) - CREDITS: @[LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)

So then you get

```php
// Add a Header
function my_shop_order_column( $columns ) {
    // Add new column
    $columns['first_order'] = 'First order';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'my_shop_order_column', 10, 1 );

// Populate the Column
function my_shop_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'first_order' ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

        // Get user id
        $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
        
        // Set variable
        $output = '';
        
        // Not a guest
        if ( $user_id > 0 ) {
            // Get the total orders by a customer.
            $count = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id );
        } else {
            // Guest 'user', don't have a user id so we will determine the previous orders based on the billing email
            
            // Get billing email
            $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
            
            if ( ! empty ( $billing_email ) ) {
                // Call function
                $count = has_guest_bought_by_email( $billing_email );
            }
        }
        
        // Output
        if ( $count == 1 ) {
            $output = 'First order';
        } elseif ( $count > 1 ) {
            $output = 'Total orders = ' . $count;
        }
        
        echo $output;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'my_shop_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );

// CREDITS: @LoicTheAztec - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216073/11987538
function has_guest_bought_by_email( $email ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Get all order statuses.
    $order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ) );

    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_billing_email'
        AND pm.meta_value = '$email'
    " );

    // Return result
    return count( $results ); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works great.
The only thing is that I have specially `if ($ count == 1)` in `if ($ count == 0)`
Because orders are also created by guest users.
Just to clarify what you sent me, does the count function linked to $ id_user also count the user buy as a guest a second time?