# How to get the customer type in Woocommerce Order List in Optimal Way

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce Order list, i want to add a column of customer type to be either "New" or "Returning" for both guest and registered customers..I have achieved that with following via below link...

**[How to add a first order column to the admin order list for customers and guests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61773416/how-to-add-a-first-order-column-to-the-admin-order-list-for-customers-and-guests)**

The code works but there is a problem that it has increased the page load time due to SQL query in for fetching the data of guest customers..it is very slow....is there's any optimal way to achieve the same thing without using SQL queries for both the customers(returning and guest) customers?

I have also tried the using the snippets from below links but it didn't help

[Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce)

Comment: I am unsure if you can code or not, but using **transient** cache is a better solution to handle slow query issues.

Comment: How to achieve that in a wordpress website...I mean that existing code which i am using executes almost 1000+ sql queries per page load of an individual guest customer..,,and due to that the page load is taking alomost 15-20 seconds to load...