# WooCommerce: Automatically change the user role after a certain quantity of completed orders or a minimum amount in one order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

I want to change automaticly user role to Premium after

- 3 **completed** orders
- Spending minimum 500 cash in one order

I found on internet this two code snipets :

```php
function change_privategroup_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];

    if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {

              // Insert the Product IDs Here. If Multiple Products seperate by ||
      if ( $product_id == '7026' || $product_id == '7027' || $product_id == '7028' || $product_id == '7029') {

                  // Mention the group number below. Here it is group1.
                  update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'private_group', 'group1');

      }
    }
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_privategroup_on_purchase' );
```

---

And this one to access order history:

Source: [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875458/11987538)

```php
function has_bought() {
    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 3, // one order is enough
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Only orders with "completed" status
        'fields'      => 'ids', // Return Ids "completed"
    ) );

    // return "true" when customer has already at least one order (false if not)
   return count($customer_orders) > 3 ?  true : false; 
}
```

---

How I can tweak them to make it work ?
Thank you in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The custom function to get the number of `completed orders` by `user id` is based on [`get_order_count( &$customer );`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/85a077b939b44500fc01b68d34e711117545f586/includes/data-stores/class-wc-customer-data-store.php#L349-L377)

```php
/**
 * Return the number of orders this customer has.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param WC_Customer $customer Customer object.
 * @return integer
 */
public function get_order_count( &$customer ) {
    $count = get_user_meta( $customer->get_id(), '_order_count', true );

    if ( '' === $count ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $count = $wpdb->get_var(
            // phpcs:disable WordPress.DB.PreparedSQL.NotPrepared
            "SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
            WHERE   meta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
            AND     posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND     posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ) ) ) . "' )
            AND     meta_value = '" . esc_sql( $customer->get_id() ) . "'"
            // phpcs:enable
        );
        update_user_meta( $customer->get_id(), '_order_count', $count );
    }

    return absint( $count );
}
```

---

So we get

- The conditions can be adjusted via the settings
- A flag is used in the usermeta table, so that the whole code is not unnecessarily rerun if one is already a premium member
- `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook is used - this hook changes a field value after a Woocommerce order is completed
- Explanation via comments added in the code

```php
// Based on https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/85a077b939b44500fc01b68d34e711117545f586/includes/data-stores/class-wc-customer-data-store.php#L349-L377
function total_completed_orders( $the_user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        // phpcs:disable WordPress.DB.PreparedSQL.NotPrepared
        "SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
        WHERE   meta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND     posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND     posts.post_status = 'wc-completed'
        AND     meta_value = '" . esc_sql( $the_user_id ) . "'"
        // phpcs:enable
    );

    // Return a boolean value based on orders count
    return $count;
}

function action_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id ) {
    /*** Settings ***/
    
    // User role in which the customer role must be changed
    $premium_user_role = 'premium';
    
    // Spending min cash in one order
    $min_in_one_order = 500;
    
    // Change role after x completed orders
    $change_role_after_x_completed_orders = 3;
    
    /*** End settings ***/
    
    $flag = false;
    
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Is a order
    if( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Get user ID or $order->get_customer_id();
        $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
        
        // Retrieve user meta field for a user. 
        $is_premium = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_customer_is_premium_member', true );
        
        // Is NOT a premium member
        if ( $is_premium != 1 ) {
            // Count total completed orders
            $total_completed_orders = total_completed_orders( $user_id );
            
            // Total completed orders greater than or equal to change role after x completed orders
            if ( $total_completed_orders >= $change_role_after_x_completed_orders ) {
                $flag = true;
            } else {
                // Get current order total
                $order_total = $order->get_total();
                
                // Order total greater than or equal to minimum in one order
                if ( $order_total >= $min_in_one_order ) {
                    $flag = true;
                }
            }
            
            // True, at least 1 condition has been met
            if ( $flag ) {
                // Get the user object
                $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

                // Get all the user roles as an array.
                $user_roles = $user->roles;
                
                // User role contains 'customer'
                if ( in_array( 'customer', $user_roles ) ) {
                    // Remove customer role
                    $user->remove_role( 'customer' );
                    
                    // Add premium role
                    $user->add_role( $premium_user_role );
                    
                    // Update user meta field based on user ID, set true
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_customer_is_premium_member', 1 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 1 );
```