# Pass Woocommerce email field value to the functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a simple piece of code which will verify if the customers email is already in the database (we don't want to allow to use the coupon without previous purchases).

I have following piece of code:

```
function check_coupon_code( $coupon ){
    
    $coupon_code = 'TEST';
    $found = false;

    // CHECK
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // CHECK END
    
    return $found;
}

//  Validity checking
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'is_it_valid', 10, 2);
function is_it_valid( $valid, $coupon ) {
    if( check_coupon_code( $coupon ) ){
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}

// Validity checking error message
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_error', 'coupon_returning_customer_error_message', 10, 3);
function coupon_returning_customer_error_message( $err, $err_code, $coupon ) {
    if( intval($err_code) === WC_COUPON::E_WC_COUPON_INVALID_FILTERED && check_coupon_code( $coupon ) ) {
        $err = __( "Coupon valid only for returning customers", "woocommerce" );
    }
    return $err;
}`
```

How I can pass the email provided in the billing_email field to the functions.php so I can use it on the backend?

///EDIT

```
// validation of adding coupons to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'coupon_returning_customer_error_message' );
function coupon_returning_customer_error_message( $coupon_code ) {
    // if the user is not logged in or has never made a purchase
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    if (has_bought($order->get_billing_email())) {
        // removes the coupon
        WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
        // clear the notices
        wc_clear_notices();
        // shows the error message
        wc_print_notice( sprintf( __( 'Coupon <strong>%s</strong> valid only for returning customers' ), $coupon_code ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

///FINAL VERSION

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'force_non_logged_user_wc_session' );
function force_non_logged_user_wc_session(){ 
    if( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
       return;
    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) 
       WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true ); 
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_billing_email_js_ajax' );
function checkout_billing_email_js_ajax() {
    // Only on Checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    // Initializing
    WC()->session->set('first_purchase_discount', false);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;
        $( 'input#billing_email' ).on('change blur', function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checkout_billing_email',
                    'cb_email': value,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if( result == 1 ) {
                        // Update checkout
                        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                    }}});});});
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// The Wordpress Ajax PHP receiver
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checkout_billing_email', 'get_ajax_checkout_billing_email' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checkout_billing_email', 'get_ajax_checkout_billing_email' );

function get_ajax_checkout_billing_email() {
    // Checking that the posted email is valid
    if ( isset($_POST['cb_email']) && filter_var($_POST['cb_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        // Set the value in custom Woocommerce session identifier
        WC()->session->set('email_session', sanitize_email( $_POST['cb_email'] ));
    }
    die();
}

// validation of adding coupons to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'coupon_returning_customer_error_message' );
function coupon_returning_customer_error_message( $coupon_code ) {
    
    function has_bought( $value = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Based on user ID (registered users)
    if ( is_numeric( $value) ) { 
        $meta_key   = '_customer_user';
        $meta_value = $value == 0 ? (int) get_current_user_id() : (int) $value;
    } 
    // Based on billing email (Guest users)
    else { 
        $meta_key   = '_billing_email';
        $meta_value = sanitize_email( $value );
    }
    $paid_order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );
   
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '%s'
        AND pm.meta_value = %s
        LIMIT 1
    ", $meta_key, $meta_value ) );

    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
    }
    // if the user is not logged in or has never made a purchase
    if(! WC()->session->get('email_session')) {
        // removes the coupon
            WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
            // clear the notices
            wc_clear_notices();
            // shows the error message
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( __( 'Enter email address to use coupon.' ), $coupon_code ), 'error' );
    } else {
        if (! has_bought(WC()->session->get('email_session'))) {
            // removes the coupon
            WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
            // clear the notices
            wc_clear_notices();
            // shows the error message
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( __( 'Coupon valid only for returning customers.' ), $coupon_code ), 'error' );}
    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a customer has placed at least one order *(with the status **wc-completed**)* you can use the conditional function `has_bought()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/46216073#46216073) and add it in your active theme's functions.php file.

Then you can use the `woocommerce_applied_coupon` hook *(which is triggered when a coupon has been applied)* as follows:

```
// validation of adding coupons to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'coupon_returning_customer_error_message' );
function coupon_returning_customer_error_message( $coupon_code ) {
    // if the user is not logged in or has never made a purchase
    if ( ! has_bought() || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // removes the coupon
        WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
        // clear the notices
        wc_clear_notices();
        // shows the error message
        wc_print_notice( sprintf( __( 'Kupon <strong>%s</strong> jest ważny wyłącznie na ponowne zakupy' ), $coupon_code ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: That is a nice answer @Vdgaetano +1

Comment: Thank you. Although, I need to check also guest users (we don't have "create your account" functionality), so I have created a piece of code using your "Update 2020" version (visible in the question) but it doesn't want to work - returns _billing_email without any value.

Comment: After 12 hours of working on it I made the final code which works like a charm.It might be ugly, but what's important, it works. I've put the final version in the question section.

It makes it possible to use the coupon only if the email address is in the database (with previous orders) and works on the checkout page without reloading.

Comment: Thanks, even if you wrote part of the answer @LoicTheAztec +1

Comment: @Vdgaetano Do you think that code I've posted poses any thread to the security of the website? Or it's just overcomplicated? :-) Basing on my experience I can say, that the more the code is complicated, the more vulnerabilities it may have. Thank you.