# Check if customer has purchased something and add product to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

The code below auto add a product to cart in WooCommerce:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 64;
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

The answer [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/46216073#46216073) allows to check if user has already make a purchase or not with a custom conditional function `has_bought()`.

So what I would like is to check if the customer has ordered before and:

- If it's their first order, force product A into the cart OR
- If they've already made one or more purchases, force product B into
  the cart

But I didn't find the way to use it in my code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses [the custom function `has_bought()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216073/6524149). It auto add to cart a different product for new customers and confirmed customers:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart_conditionally' );
function add_product_to_cart_conditionally() {
    if ( is_admin() )  return; // Exit

    // Below define the product Id to be added:
    $product_A = 37; // <== For new customers that have not purchased a product before (and guests)
    $product_B = 53; // <== For confirmed customers that have purchased a product before

    $product_id = has_bought() ? $product_B : $product_A;

    // If cart is empty
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ); // Add the product
    }
    // If cart is not empty
    else {
        // Loop through cart items (check cart items)
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
            // Check if the product is already in cart
            if ( $item['product_id'] == $product_id ) {
                return; // Exit if the product is in cart
            }
        }
        // The product is not in cart: We add it
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/46216073#46216073)