# Allow customers to buy only one product from defined WooCommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I want to let customers buy only one product from a defined category. All products are priced as 0 (zero). Only delivery fee is charged.

I referred to the same scenario and tried this code. But this code fails for not logged in users. When I try multiple purchases I have no matter of buying. Want to limit after the first successful attempt of a purchase. I am using the child theme `functions.php` file.

**Note:** customers do not need to register in the website before doing a purchase.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation','filter_add_to_cart_validation',20, 2);
function filter_add_to_cart_validation($valid, $product_id){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id) && has_term( array('free-giveaway'), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You already bought an item. Let others to buy as well.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Explanation/comments related to the answer:

- The [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) WordPress function is used to check the product category
- It is better to only apply these kinds of checks (has bought before) **for logged in users**, since usually no data is known from customers. However, it is possible that you can obtain the e-mail address via [WC_Customer](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Customer.html). (**this will not always suffice**, hence my comment to only apply this to logged in users)
- **Note:** the `has_bought()` function is copied and pasted from [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216073/11987538) answer code

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Set (multiple) categories
    $categories = array ( 'free-giveaway', 'categorie-1' );
    
    // If passed & has category
    if ( $passed && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        // Initialize
        $value = '';

        // User logged in
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            // Get the current user's ID 
            $value = get_current_user_id();
        } else {
            // Get billing_email
            $value = WC()->customer->get_billing_email();

            // When empty
            if ( empty ( $value ) ) {
                // Get account email
                $value = WC()->customer->get_email();   
            }
        }

        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $value ) ) {
            if ( has_bought( $value ) ) {
                // Display an error message
                wc_add_notice( __( 'My custom error message', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

                // False
                $passed = false;
            }
        }       
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );

// Based partially on wc_customer_bought_product(), will return a boolean value based on orders count (false for O orders and true when there is at least one paid order)
function has_bought( $value = 0 ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $value === 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    
    // Based on user ID (registered users)
    if ( is_numeric( $value ) ) { 
        $meta_key   = '_customer_user';
        $meta_value = $value == 0 ? (int) get_current_user_id() : (int) $value;
    } 
    // Based on billing email (Guest users)
    else { 
        $meta_key   = '_billing_email';
        $meta_value = sanitize_email( $value );
    }
    
    $paid_order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '%s'
        AND pm.meta_value = %s
        LIMIT 1
    ", $meta_key, $meta_value ) );

    // Return a boolean value based on orders count
    return $count > 0;
}
```

Comment: My answer clearly states the following: **It is better to only apply these kinds of checks (has bought before) for logged in users**, since usually no data is known from customers. However, it is possible that you can obtain the e-mail address via WC_Customer. **THIS WILL NOT ALWAYS SUFFICE..**.