# woocommerce limit users buy two products within x amount of time

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I would like to add a quanity eg 2 which users are allowed to buy within its timeframe. Also the error notice message is showing on the product page. How would I go about letting the product added to cart and the error message showing on the cart page?

Based on [Allow customers to buy only one product from defined WooCommerce product category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71347475/11987538) answer code, here is my code attempt:

```
// Based partially on wc_customer_bought_product(), will return a boolean value based on orders count (false for O orders and true when there is at least one paid order)
function has_bought( $value = 0 ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $value === 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    
    // Based on user ID (registered users)
    if ( is_numeric( $value ) ) { 
        $meta_key   = '_customer_user';
        $meta_value = $value == 0 ? (int) get_current_user_id() : (int) $value;
    } 
    // Based on billing email (Guest users)
    else { 
        $meta_key   = '_billing_email';
        $meta_value = sanitize_email( $value );
    }
    
    $paid_order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );



    $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '%s'
        AND pm.meta_value = %s
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400 * 1))
        LIMIT 1
    ", $meta_key, $meta_value ) );

    // Return a boolean value based on orders count
    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}




function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Set categories
    $categories = array ( 'kitchen' );
    
    // If passed & has category
    if ( $passed && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        // Initialize
        $value = '';

        // User logged in
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            // Get the current user's ID 
            $value = get_current_user_id();
        } else {
            // Get billing_email
            $value = WC()->customer->get_billing_email();

            // When empty
            if ( empty ( $value ) ) {
                // Get account email
                $value = WC()->customer->get_email();   
            }
        }
        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $value ) ) {
            if ( has_bought( $value ) ) {
                // Display an error message
                wc_add_notice( __( 'My custom error message', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

                // False
                $passed = false;
            }
        }       
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: You want to add the time limit to buy the products and after time limit get over it will remove from the purchase list right?

Comment: hey Kairav no, the time limit is already added, AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400 * 1))

Comment: Got it. Let me check

Comment: but when an order is made in the kitchen catergory the time limit begins which is great BUT I wanted the user to be able to make 2 orders of the catergory within the time limit!

Comment: Okay, So time limit functionality is started after order purchase for the category define

Comment: and let user make just one more or x amount more orders within that catergory within the time

Comment: hey Kairav any guidence on how to add this?

Comment: Will make the work in my website and then will come back to the conclusion and share it with you soon.