# Add custom field for WooCommerce CSV Export plugin - For customer first order

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, orders

I'm using **Woocommerce CSV Export** plugin. 
I will like to have a way to check if the customer is NEW and if it is, to write in order metadata for a **custom `meta-key`** a **`true` value**. 
But if user is not New, nothing will happen.

I thought first to start with the creation date of the WP user (user_registered). But I think there is a better and faster way.  In other words, how can I know if this is the first order of a client...

**My goal:** If this customer is ordering for the first time, have a **`TRUE`** value, for this order in the Export CSV.

Then I have tried [to use this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/) without success.

**My question:** 
How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is not an "I need this; give me code" service. There are search engines for that. Please provide some code that you have already tried/having issues with in order to get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [**this answer code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/38875458#38875458) *(I have recently made)*, it's possible to have a function that will add a meta key/value in the database **`wp_postmeta`** table for a New customer first order. So we will change a bit that conditional function this way:

```
function new_customer_has_bought() {

    $count = 0;
    $new_customer = false;

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id()
    ) );

    // Going through each current customer orders
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $count++;
    }

    // return "true" when it is the first order for this customer
    if ( $count > 2 ) // or ( $count == 1 )
        $new_customer = true;

    return $new_customer;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme or theme, or in a plugin php file.*

---

**USAGE IN THANKYOU HOOK:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'tracking_new_customer' );
function tracking_new_customer( $order_id ) {

    // Exit if no Order  ID
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // The paid orders are changed to "completed" status
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );

    // For 1st 'completed' costumer paid order status
    if ( new_customer_has_bought() && $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) 
    { 
        // Create 'first_order' custom field with 'true' value
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'first_order', 'true' ); needed)
    }
    else  // For all other customer paid orders
    {
        // udpdate existing  'first_order' CF to '' value (empty)
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'first_order', '' );
    }
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme or theme, or in a plugin php file.*

> Now **only** for the **FIRST new customer order** you will have a custom meta data which **key** is **`'_first_customer_order'`** and **value** is **true**.

**To get this this value** for a defined order ID, you will use this (last argument means it's a string):

```
// Getting the value for a defined $order_id
$first_customer_order = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'first_order', false );

// to display it
echo $first_customer_order;
```

**All the code is tested and works.**

---

References

- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/38875458#38875458)
- [Check if a customer has purchased a specific product earlier in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-customer-has-purchased-a-specific-product-earlier-in-woocommerce/38772202#38772202)
- [WP Code Reference - update_post_meta() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)
- [WP Code Reference - get_post_meta() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: I will test that tomorrow. Thank you to share.