# WooCommerce - Checking if my first variable subscription item is sold

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, product, subscriptions

I have two Questions:

### Question 1:

I am using a "Woocommerce product bundle" and "Woocommerce subscriptions" plugins and want to restrict my FIRST variable subscription item to restrict to sold to only one customer? In other words no other customer can buy it if one customer is already subscribe to it.

### Question 2:

Also How do I check in the custom loop if the customer is subscribe so I can exclude that product from my archive product page?

Thanks!

Comment: When a customer select a subscription and checkout/order, an order is generated (post_type => 'shop_order') with a related subscription (post_type => 'shop_subscription'). when this order is paid you can use woocommerce_thankyou hook to detect this item on the order and then exclude the product (see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38986593/3730754) of different usage for this hook. You can with a foreach loop get the items in the order (products)… so exclude an item from shop (each order/subscription is related to a customer)…

Comment: Hi, I don't want to exclude the entire product, I only want to restrict FIRST "variable subscription" ITEM from the list, Since I am using "Woocommerce product bundle" I have some other items attached to the product but I only want to restrict first item if already purchased by someone.

Comment: I haven't use Woocommerce product bundle yet… so I can't really tell about: You have to look in your database to see how data is arranged for your bundled product (in wp_post and wp_postmeta) and for your order/subscription too. Or alternatively use var_dump() function on $product, $order and $subscription object. This way you will find how you can use foreach loops to access to the data you need.