# WooCommerce - Check if user purchased a product in the past 60 days

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am new to WooCommerce and wanted to check if a user has purchased a specific product (product id # 514) within the past 60 days. This is a product I let people purchase monthly, so it will reoccur a lot. I wanted to just see if they purchased a recent one (that I consider active)

The way I was thinking of doing it now was:

1. Get all orders from a user
2. For each order, check if it occurred in the past 60 days
   and and get all products for this order
3. For each product, see if the id is x

While I'm sure this will work, I have a funny feeling there is a really concise **get_posts(apply_filters(**  query that will save me some looping time.

Would anyone be wiling to share a few ideas or a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a conditional function partially based on the built-in woocommerce function [`wc_customer_bought_product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_customer_bought_product.html) source code query:

There is an 3 optional argument `$user_id`, `$product_ids` and `$days`:

- `$user_id` will allow you to specify a defined user ID (when is not used for current logged in user);
- `$product_ids` (string or an array) will allow to specify defined product Ids to check
- `$days`will allow you to specify the number of days to search for *(or the period if you prefer)*…

The code function:

```
function has_bought_multi( $user_id = 0,  $product_ids = 0, $days = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 || $user_id == '' ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $statuses      = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$days day") );

    if ( is_array( $product_ids ) )
        $product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);

    if ( $product_ids !=  ( 0 || '' ) )
        $query_line = "AND woim.meta_value IN ($product_ids)";
    else
        $query_line = "AND woim.meta_value != 0";

    // Count the number of products
    $product_count_query = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT COUNT(woim.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_date > '$date'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        $query_line
    " );
    // Set the count in a string
    $count = reset($product_count_query);

    // Return a boolean value if count is higher than 0
    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Similar answer: [Check if a customer has purchased a specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-customer-has-purchased-a-specific-products-in-woocommerce/46217461#46217461)

---

USAGE EXAMPLE (Customer is logged in):

Detecting if current user has bought your product id # 514 in past 60 days:

```
if( has_bought_multi( '', 514, 60 ) ){
    echo "<p>Customer has bought product id # 514 in past 60 days</p>";
    // do something
} else {
    echo "<p>Customer <strong>HAS NOT</strong> bought product id # 514 in past 60 days</p>";
    // do something else
}
```