# Get the orders IDs related to a product bought by a customer in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I have the products ids as an array and I would like to get the list of order ids if the customer has purchased that product.

I have the customer purchased product ids with me. Somehow, I have to get the linked order id and cancel that order if customer purchases new product.

To check if a customer has purchased a product I am using the function `has_bought_items()` from this answer thread: [Check if a customer has purchased a specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-customer-has-purchased-a-specific-products-in-woocommerce/38772202#38772202)

May be it can be tweaked to get the desired output?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following custom function made with a very light unique SQL query, will get all the Orders IDs from an array of products IDs (or a unique product ID) for a given customer.

> Based on code from: [Check if a customer has purchased a specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-customer-has-purchased-a-specific-products-in-woocommerce/46217461#46217461)

```
function get_order_ids_from_bought_items( $product_ids = 0, $customer_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $customer_id = $customer_id == 0 || $customer_id == '' ? get_current_user_id() : $customer_id;
    $statuses    = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    if ( is_array( $product_ids ) )
        $product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);

    if ( $product_ids !=  ( 0 || '' ) )
        $meta_query_line = "AND woim.meta_value IN ($product_ids)";
    else
        $meta_query_line = "AND woim.meta_value != 0";

    // Get Orders IDs
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        $meta_query_line
    " );

    // Return an array of Order IDs or an empty array
    return sizeof($results) > 0 ? $results : array();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### USAGE Examples:

1) For the current logged in customer (and 2 product Ids in an array):

```
$product_ids = array(37,53);
$order_ids = get_order_ids_from_bought_items( $product_ids );
```

2) For a defined User ID and one product ID:

```
$product_id = 53;
$user_id    = 72;
$order_ids  = get_order_ids_from_bought_items( $product_id, $user_id );
```

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla What do you mean, you are getting which Order ID? You mean that you are getting Orders IDs that have not the product in them (so orders IDs not related to that product ID)?

Comment: yes. i have 3 orders and i gave two product ids but it returned all three orders

Comment: yes, i have related and unrelated order id in the result(to the product ID passed)