# Change order status to 'cancelled' for earlier orders if user purchases specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to change the order status to cancelled for earlier purchases if user purchases a specific product (an array of product ids)

I am using the custom function `get_order_ids_from_bought_items()` [from this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863379/3697484) that allow me to get the orders Ids for a specific customer that match with given product ids.

```
// The defined product IDs
product_ids = array(183,153);

$linked_order_ids = get_order_ids_from_bought_items(product_ids); //output : array(12,13);
```

if customer buys any of this products ===> `$special products = array(1788,123);`

> **I want to change the `$linked_order_ids` status to canceled**

As `get_order_ids_from_bought_items()` will also have the last order I am removing the last item form the output of that function using `array_pop($linked_order_ids );`

#### Complete Code

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'woo_order_status_change_custom', 10, 3);
function changestatus()
{
    $product_ids = $newcustomer->wpprolister_array_intersect();

    $orderidstoremove = get_order_ids_from_bought_items($product_ids );
    $removed          = array_pop($orderidstoremove);

    foreach ($removed as $remove) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $remove );
        $order->update_status('cancelled', 'As you have brought new package this package has been cancelled');
    }

}
```

But is not working for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using this hook you can't use the **current user id**, instead you need to retrieve the **user Id** from the `WC_Order` object… Then `$newcustomer->wpprolister_array_intersect()` can't work.

You will have to change all your related existing functions code to be able to handle a defined user ID

Also The name of your function doesn't match with the hooked callback slug *(in `add_action()` )*…

So your code will have to be something like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'wc_order_uppdate_to_cancelled_status', 20, 4 );
function wc_order_uppdate_to_cancelled_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // Targetting "processing" and "completed" orders status.
    if ( in_array( $new_status, array('processing', 'completed') ) ) {
        // Get the user ID
        $user_id  = $order->get_customer_id();

        $product_ids = wpprolister_array_intersect($user_id); // <== Changes in this function will be needed

        $matching_orders_ids    = get_order_ids_from_bought_items( $product_ids, $user_id );
        $orders_to_be_cancelled = array_pop( $orders_to_remove );

        foreach ( array_pop( $matching_orders_ids ) as $cancelled_order_id ) {
            $cancelled_order = wc_get_order( $cancelled_order_id );
            $$cancelled_order->update_status('cancelled', 'As you have brought new package this package has been cancelled');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi..do i have to pass $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order to make the function work?