# Make a product to be purchased only once or not if any item from a specific product category has been purchased in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In woocommerce, I am just using simple products and I have a special product "free trial package" from a product category "A", which I'm willing to:

1. **let the customer only purchase this "free trial package" once** …
2. **if the customer buy other products from the same product category "A" first, then the customer can't purchase this "free trial package" anymore**

This means the customer only be able to get the "free trial package" only if it's the first purchase of that product category "A".

My code doesn't seem to work properly and it only do the 1st point.

The other problem is that if the user order finishes, next time user open cart it shows a weird message:
*"you cant select this product anymore, you already bought this package"*.It's like Woocommerce cache problem or something…

Here is my code so far:

```
function sv_disable_repeat_purchase( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $non_purchasable = 190;

    $product_id = $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->variation_id : $product->id;

    if ( $product_id != $non_purchasable ) {
        $purchasable = true;
    }

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    if ( $purchasable && $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $purchasable = $product->parent->is_purchasable();
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'sv_disable_repeat_purchase', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'sv_disable_repeat_purchase', 10, 2 );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

Based on *"[Check if a customer has purchased a specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-customer-has-purchased-a-specific-products-in-woocommerce/46217461#46217461)"* answer code, the following will prevent purchases from a "trial package" product, if it has already been purchased once, or if any product for a defined product category "A" has been already purchased.

Your actual code is outdated since Woocommerce 3 and there some mistakes…

I use a custom conditional function inspired from [`wc_customer_bought_product()` source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_customer_bought_product.html#202-259), to check if customer can buy the "free trial" product. This function will check as well for a product ID or for a product category:

```
function has_bought_items( $user_id = 0, $product_ids = 0, $categories_slugs = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 || $user_id == '' ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $statuses    = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    if ( is_array( $product_ids ) ) {
        $product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);
    }

    if ( $product_ids !=  ( 0 || '' ) ) {
        $query_in = "IN ($product_ids)";
    }
    else {
        $categories = is_array( $categories_slugs ) ? implode("','", $categories_slugs) : $categories_slugs;

        $query_in = "IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT products.ID  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as term_rel
            ON products.ID = term_rel.object_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as term_tax
            ON term_rel.term_taxonomy_id = term_tax.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as terms
            ON term_tax.term_taxonomy_id = terms.term_id
        WHERE products.post_status = 'publish'
        AND term_tax.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        AND terms.slug IN ('$categories')
        )";
    }

    // Count the number of products
    $product_count_query = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(orders.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS orders
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS order_meta
            ON orders.ID = order_meta.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items
            ON orders.ID = order_items.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_itemmeta
            ON order_items.order_item_id = order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        WHERE orders.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
        AND order_meta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND order_meta.meta_value = $customer_id
        AND order_itemmeta.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND order_itemmeta.meta_value $query_in
    " );

    // Return a boolean value if count is higher than 0
    return $product_count_query > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Your revisited code using the custom conditional function above:

```
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'trial_package_purchasable_once', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'trial_package_purchasable_once', 10, 2 );
function trial_package_purchasable_once( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // HERE set the free trial product Id to be purchased only once (can be an array of Ids too)
    $free_trial_id = 50;

    // HERE set the specific product category SLUG (could be an array of slugs too)
    $categories = array('lettering'); // Only slug terms

        if ( $product->get_id() == $free_trial_id ) {
            // Check if any item of the specific product category has already been purchased once
            if ( has_bought_items( get_current_user_id(), '', $categories ) ) {
                return false;
            }
            // Check if the free trial product has already been purchased once
            elseif ( has_bought_items( get_current_user_id(), $free_trial_id ) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To handle product categories Term IDs instead of Term Slugs use the following conditional function instead:

```
// For Product category(ies) Id(s)
function has_bought_items( $user_id = 0, $product_ids = 0, $categories_ids = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 || $user_id == '' ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $statuses    = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    if ( is_array( $product_ids ) ) {
        $product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);
    }

    if ( $product_ids !=  ( 0 || '' ) ) {
        $query_in = "IN ($product_ids)";
    }
    else {
        $categories = is_array( $categories_ids ) ? implode(',', $categories_ids) : $categories_ids;

        $query_in = "IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT products.ID  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as term_rel
            ON products.ID = term_rel.object_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as term_tax
            ON term_rel.term_taxonomy_id = term_tax.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as terms
            ON term_tax.term_taxonomy_id = terms.term_id
        WHERE products.post_status = 'publish'
        AND term_tax.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        AND terms.term_id IN ($categories)
        )";
    }

    // Count the number of products
    $product_count_query = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(orders.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS orders
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS order_meta
            ON orders.ID = order_meta.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items
            ON orders.ID = order_items.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_itemmeta
            ON order_items.order_item_id = order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        WHERE orders.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
        AND order_meta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND order_meta.meta_value = $customer_id
        AND order_itemmeta.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND order_itemmeta.meta_value $query_in
    " );

    // Return a boolean value if count is higher than 0
    return $product_count_query > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

It's better alternative for foreign languages with special characters.

Comment: it doesnt work, I first purchased $20 package, then I tried to bought free package and I did!

Comment: what it actualy does is this, it lets you buy whatever, as soon as you buy free package you cant buy anything else !

what I want is this, only if you order free package as a starting purchase you can buy it, but if you do that you cant purchase it again
also if you buy anything esle other than free package you cant select free package again

Comment: when I purchase free package ,not only it wont let me purchase from the same category but it wont let me purchase again at all! the add to cart button disappear completely on all things!

Comment: hmmm the code seems it needs some sort of return in each if

Comment: it works perfectly, the only problem is my category slug is not english, so it doesnt detect it somehow ...

Comment: I have added a new replacement conditional function at the end that check for categories term Ids, which should work for all foreign languages with special characters.

Comment: Hey man, We recently change slug of some of our categories for SEO purposes, Is there a way this function has_bought_items( $user_id = 0, $product_ids = 0, $categories_slugs = '' )  change in way that work with CATEGORY NAME like has_term() function ?? because Our slugs is not in English and this only works with English slugs

Comment: On first function replace `AND terms.slug IN ($categories)` by `AND terms.name IN ($categories)` … Or on last function `AND terms.term_id IN ($categories)` by `AND terms.name IN ($categories)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function wc_customer_purchased_product_in_cat( $product ) {

    // enter the category for which a single purchase is allowed
    $non_repeatable = 'ADD YOUR CATEGORY HERE';

    // bail if this product is in not in our target category
    if ( ! has_term( $non_repeatable, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // the product has our target category, so return whether the customer purchased
    return wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() );
}

function wc_disable_repeat_purchase( $purchasable, $product ) {

    if ( wc_customer_purchased_product_in_cat( $product ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    // double-check for variations: if parent is not purchasable, then variation is not
    if ( $purchasable && $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $purchasable = $product->parent->is_purchasable();
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'wc_disable_repeat_purchase', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wc_disable_repeat_purchase', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: where the product id goes ?!