# How to list all users not currently logged in and check if each user has bought a specific product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There is page in my WordPress WooCommerce website that list all registered users, my question is I wanted to show a verification message next to each user, if there have purchased a product.

**Notes:**

- "Not Verified" is for those users that have not purchased the woocommerce product.
- Its a digital WooCommerce product

Example:

1. User1 - Verified
2. User2 - Verified
3. User3 - Not Verified
4. User4 - Verified
5. User5 - Verified
6. User6 - Not Verified

I am using a function from *[Check if a user has purchased specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-user-has-purchased-specific-products-in-woocommerce/46217461#46217461)*  answer to  check if a user has already bought some products.

My code usage is:

```
// Define the targeted Products IDs
$product_ids = array( 38, 41, 85, 95 );

//Get UserIds
$user_ids = get_current_user_id();

if( has_bought_items( $user_ids, $product_ids ) )
    echo "<p>Verified</p>";
else
    echo "<p>Not Verified</p>";
```

The problem is when i use it, it will display/mark every users "Verified" even wen some users haven't purchased the products.. e.g

1. User1 - Verified
2. User2 - Verified
3. User3 - Verified
4. User4 - Verified
5. User5 - Verified
6. User6 - Verified

I don't know if my code is wrong or not.

Comment: I have updated [my original function `has_bought_items()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-user-has-purchased-specific-products-in-woocommerce/46217461#46217461) as there was some oversights… Now to use the current user id, just use it this way: `if( has_bought_items(0, $product_ids) {` so you just need to define `$product_ids` variable before using it. Note: You can check "guests" only from their billing email when it's available…

Comment: Now you should provide in your question the related code from your WordPress page where you are trying to use this conditional function and on this page you should use each defined user ID** with that conditional function.

Comment: Your code works quite well, but my problem is i want to display the users to the public those that has bought my woocommerce product to everyone on the website with the tag "Verified". if they haven't bought my product, they will still be listed but the tag will show "Unverified".

Comment: Note: I'm using a wordpress theme that displays list of users. and i want to match each users to their equivalent user id in order to display who has bought the product or not.