# Avoid guest purchases if a product has been purchased before on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

for various reasons a webshop needs to allow guest orders, but then saves the data to an existing user if the email is already registered. However, a product (parent variable product) should not be bought twice.
In that case, the customer should be returned to the checkout page and get a notice that this product is already bought.

So far i have the following code (not complete):

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', function () {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && $_POST['billing_email'] && $_POST['createaccount'] == 1) {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $_POST['billing_email']);
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        if (!empty($user)){
            if (wc_customer_bought_product($user->user_email,$user->ID,$product_id))
            return false;
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
        }
        if (!empty($user)) {
        if (wc_customer_bought_product($user->user_email,$user->ID,$product_id)) 
            return true;
        exit;
    }
    else{
        ///guest, continue
    }
}}});
```

But that gives only an internal server error.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of using `wc_customer_bought_product()`, you can use the following enhanced conditional function from [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217461/3730754) *(based on the same source code than `wc_customer_bought_product()`)*. This function will handle your variable products case.

```
// Conditional function( stackOverFlow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217461/3730754 )
function has_bought_items( $user_var = 0,  $product_ids = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Based on user ID (registered users)
    if ( is_numeric( $user_var) ) { 
        $meta_key     = '_customer_user';
        $meta_value   = $user_var == 0 ? (int) get_current_user_id() : (int) $user_var;
    } 
    // Based on billing email (Guest users)
    else { 
        $meta_key     = '_billing_email';
        $meta_value   = sanitize_email( $user_var );
    }
    
    $paid_statuses    = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );
    $product_ids      = is_array( $product_ids ) ? implode(',', $product_ids) : $product_ids;

    $line_meta_value  = $product_ids !=  ( 0 || '' ) ? 'AND woim.meta_value IN ('.$product_ids.')' : 'AND woim.meta_value != 0';

    // Count the number of products
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_statuses ) . "' )
        AND pm.meta_key = '$meta_key'
        AND pm.meta_value = '$meta_value'
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' ) $line_meta_value 
    " );

    // Return true if count is higher than 0 (or false)
    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

You can't get yet the order or order items… **Instead you will check cart items**.

Then here is your revisited code that handle all kind of customers and variable products as asked:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_action_checkout_process' );
function wc_action_checkout_process() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // 1. - For logged in users
    if( $user_id > 0 ) {
        $user_var = $user_id;
    }
    // 2. - For others
    else {
        if ( isset($_POST['billing_email']) && ! empty($_POST['billing_email']) ) {
            $email = sanitize_email( $_POST['billing_email'] );
            $user  = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

            // 2.a - When a user exist for the billing email return an error notice
            if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('The email "%s" is already registered for "%s" user name. Please login.'), $email, $user->user_login ), 'error' );
            }
            // 2.b - User doesn't exits (real "guest")
            else {
                $user_var = $email;
            }
        }
    }

    // Loop through cart items to check products
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_bought_items( $user_var,  $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You have already purchased "%s" product before. You can only purchase it once.'), $cart_item['data']->get_name() ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Almost correct, in my case it did work with wc_customer_bought_product(). And that you do all this work for nothing... respect! Thank you!