# Disable WooCommerce products for some time if customer has purchased specific product

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, date, woocommerce

In WooCommerce would like to disable purchases from defined products ( B, C and D ) **during a month** if customer has purchased a product ( A or B ), so products B, C and D should be disabled **for a month for that specific user only**.

Note: In the code below I am using `has_bought_items()` a custom function from *[Check if a user has purchased specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769888/check-if-a-user-has-purchased-specific-products-in-woocommerce/46217461#46217461)* answer.

My code attempt:

```
$product_ids = array( 255, 256 );

$args2 = array(
    'customer_id' => get_current_user_id()
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args2 );
$orders = has_bought_items( get_current_user_id(), $product_ids );

if($orders){
    add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_product', 10, 2 );
 
    function disable_product( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
 
        if( in_array( $product->get_id(), array( 256, 257, 258 ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
 
        return $is_purchasable;
    }
}

So far I am able to disable the products for the user. But I don't how can I get date from the purchase and add a month to it. Any help will be great.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize a bit the code from `has_bought_items()` to get the highest "post date" from a customer order that has purchased product id `255` or `256` (for the current user ID).

Then using `strtotime()` function you will be able to disable purchases on other defined products during a month.

The code using a customized SQL query:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_specific_product_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function disable_specific_product_conditionally( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    $targeted_ids = array( 256, 257, 258 ); // Related targeted products to be disabled

    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $targeted_ids ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $product_ids   = array( 255, 256 ); // Check orders for this products

        // Count the number of products
        $date = $wpdb->get_var("
            SELECT p.post_date FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
            WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ) ) . "' )
            AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
            AND pm.meta_value = '".get_current_user_id()."'
            AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
            AND woim.meta_value IN (".implode(',', $product_ids).")
            ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
        ");
        
        // When a date is found we disable during a month purchases from this date
        return ! empty($date) && strtotime('now') > strtotime( $date . ' + 1 month') ? false : $is_purchasable;
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.